# Can an <option> have multiple names? Fetch data attributes of <option>?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

OK, my question is pretty simple. Can an option have 2 names? I need to use the names to get 2 groups,and then 2 sub groups.

So, say I have 2 lists of options.
Everything i list one is "X", and everything in list 2 is "C". However, every option is also something else.

List1

```
<option name="X"name1="Y">
<option name="X"name1="D">
<option name="X"name1="Y">
```

List2

`<option name="C"name1="Y">
<option name="C"name1="D">
<option name="C"name1="Y">`

So, is this possible? The first name is needed to figure out the total of the selected option multiplied by a number in an input box. (eg. option value = 3, input = 6, total 18)

The second name is needed to add a percent bonus. (eg. total = 20, enter 150%, new total is 30)

The fist name is so the computer can tell between one list and the other when using getelementsbyname.

FULL CODE---

```html
    <form action="">
      <fieldset>

        <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction() {

              /*Left flank bonus*/
              var MLef1 = document.getElementById("MeleeL").value;
              var RLef1 = document.getElementById("RangedL").value;
              var ML = MLef1 - 0;
              var RL = RLef1 - 0;
              



              /*Melee total*/
              var MT1 = ML;
              var MT2 = MT1 / 100;
              var MT = MT2 - 0;

              /*Ranged total*/
              var RT1 = RL;
              var RT2 = RT1 / 100;
              var RT = RT2 - 0;


              /*Left flank normal*/
              /*Left flank melee*/
              var x = document.getElementById("Melee").selectedIndex;
              var y = (document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value);
              var xy = document.getElementById("LM1").value;


              /*Left flank Ranged*/
              var p = document.getElementById("Ranged").selectedIndex;
              var o = (document.getElementsByName("LR")[p].value);
              var i = document.getElementById("LM1").value;

              /*Ranged*/
              var c1 = o * i;
              var c = c1 - 0;
              var RTz = c - 0;

              /*Melee*/
              var z2 = y * xy;
              var z = z2 - 0;
              var MTz = z - 0;



              /*Zero function*/

              if (MT <= 0) {
                (document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = z);
              } 
else if (MT > 0) {
                (document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = MTz);
}


              
              if (RT <= 0) {
                (document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = c);
              } else if (RT > 0) {
                (document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = RTz);



              }
            }
          </script>
          <style>
            #Defense {
              color: red;
              font-family: Impact;
              font-size: 30px;
            }
            #MeleeL {
              border-radius: 5px;
            }
            #RangedL {
              border-radius: 5px;
            }
     
            
            #Melee {
              font-family: Impact;
              color: red;
              border-radius: 5px;
            }
            #Melee1 {
              font-family: Impact;
              color: red;
              border-radius: 5px;
            }
            #Ranged {
              font-family: Impact;
              color: red;
              border-radius: 5px;
            }
          </style>

          <legend align="center" id="Defense">Defense</legend>

          <table>
            
              
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>X</label>
                <br>
                <label>Y</label>
                <br>

              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="number" id="MeleeL">%
                <br>
                <input type="number" id="RangedL">%
                <br>
        
            </tr>
          </table>

          <select id="Melee">
            <option value="11">Assassin</option>
            <option value="9">Barbarian</option>
            <option value="6">Crossbowman</option>
            <option value="14">XBOW of EG</option>
            <option value="15">XBOW of KG</option>
            <option value="15">Deathly Horror</option>
            <option value="19">Demon Horror</option>
            <option value="16">Demon Slayer</option>
            <option value="15">Heavy XBOW</option>
            <option value="54">Khan Guard</option>
            <option value="18">Knight of EG</option>
            <option value="18">Knight of KG</option>
            <option value="38">Maceman</option>
            <option value="18">Maruder</option>
            <option value="19">Pyromaniac</option>
            <option value="8">Rngd Sail Ripper</option>
            <option value="11">Rngd Swashbuckler</option>
            <option value="20">Rngd Sharktooth warrior</option>
            <option value="22">Rngd Stone Smasher</option>
            <option value="6">Saber Cleaver</option>
            <option value="20">Shadow XBOW</option>
            <option value="15">Shadow Felon</option>
            <option value="4">Shadow Mace</option>
            <option value="11">Shadow Rogue</option>
            <option value="20">Shadow Scoundrel</option>
            <option value="16">Shadow Wretch</option>
            <option value="5">Slingshot</option>
            <option value="5">Swordsman</option>
            <option value="22">Traveling XBOW</option>
            <option value="20">Traveling Knight</option>
            <option value="19">2handed Sword</option>
            <option value="16">Vet XBOW</option>
            <option value="16">Vet Heavy XBOW</option>
            <option value="20">Vet Maceman</option>
            <option value="18">Vet Marauder</option>
            <option value="19">Vet Pyromaniac</option>
            <option value="20">Vet 2Handed Sword</option>
            <option value="9">Armed Citezen</option>
            <option value="53">Archer</option>
            <option value="8">Bowman</option>
            <option value="8">Composite Bowman</option>
            <option value="51">Cultist Bowman</option>
            <option value="135">Cultist Fanatic</option>
            <option value="51">Desert Bowman</option>
            <option value="250">Dragon Claws</option>
            <option value="400">Dragon Fire</option>
            <option value="170">Flame Bearer</option>
            <option value="135">Halberdier</option>
            <option value="150">Lancer</option>
            <option value="51">Longbowman</option>
            <option value="27">Militia</option>
            <option value="64">Scout of KG</option>
            <option value="150">Sential of KG</option>
            <option value="20">Spear Thrower</option>
            <option value="26">Spearman</option>
            <option value="59">Vet Bowman</option>
            <option value="145">Vet Halberdier</option>
            <option value="61">Vet Longbowman</option>
            <option value="142">Vet Spearman</option>
            <option value="54">Bear Bowman</option>
            <option value="139">Bear Warrior</option>
            <option value="135">Boarder</option>
            <option value="51">Cave Hunter</option>
            <option value="135">Cave Smasher</option>
            <option value="40">Direwolf</option>
            <option value="54">Lion Bowman</option>
            <option value="139">Lion Warrior</option>
            <option value="135">Nrsmn with Ax</option>
            <option value="51">Nrsmn with Bow</option>
            <option value="59">Rngd Cultist Bowman</option>
            <option value="144">Rngd Cultist Warrior</option>
            <option value="54">Rngd Desert Bowman</option>
            <option value="48">Rngd Nrsmn Bowman</option>
            <option value="129">Rngd Nrsmn Warrior</option>
            <option value="137">Rngd Saber Warrior</option>
            <option value="135">Saber Warrior</option>
            <option value="135">Shark Tooth Warrior</option>
            <option value="51">Skeleton Bowman</option>
            <option value="135">Skeleton Warrior</option>
            <option value="51">Stone Smasher</option>
            <option value="138">Vet Swordsman</option>
            <option value="50">Wolfhound</option>
          </select>
          <input type="number" style="width:50px" id="LM1">
          <select id="Ranged">
            <option name="LR" value="17">Assassin</option>
            <option name="LR" value="4">Barbarian</option>
            <option name="LR" value="36">Crossbowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="23">XBOW of EG</option>
            <option name="LR" value="23">XBOW of KG</option>
            <option name="LR" value="24">Deathly Horror</option>
            <option name="LR" value="5">Demon Horror</option>
            <option name="LR" value="5">Demon Slayer</option>
            <option name="LR" value="24">Heavy XBOW</option>
            <option name="LR" value="50">Khan Guard</option>
            <option name="LR" value="5">Knight of EG</option>
            <option name="LR" value="5">Knight of KG</option>
            <option name="LR" value="6">Maceman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="4">Maruder</option>
            <option name="LR" value="4">Pyromaniac</option>
            <option name="LR" value="14">Rngd Sail Ripper</option>
            <option name="LR" value="3">Rngd Swashbuckler</option>
            <option name="LR" value="9">Rngd Sharktooth warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="30">Rngd Stone Smasher</option>
            <option name="LR" value="3">Saber Cleaver</option>
            <option name="LR" value="7">Shadow XBOW</option>
            <option name="LR" value="24">Shadow Felon</option>
            <option name="LR" value="23">Shadow Mace</option>
            <option name="LR" value="5">Shadow Rogue</option>
            <option name="LR" value="6">Shadow Scoundrel</option>
            <option name="LR" value="22">Shadow Wretch</option>
            <option name="LR" value="9">Slingshot</option>
            <option name="LR" value="3">Swordsman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="30">Traveling XBOW</option>
            <option name="LR" value="9">Traveling Knight</option>
            <option name="LR" value="5">2handed Sword</option>
            <option name="LR" value="26">Vet XBOW</option>
            <option name="LR" value="26">Vet Heavy XBOW</option>
            <option name="LR" value="6">Vet Maceman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="4">Vet Marauder</option>
            <option name="LR" value="4">Vet Pyromaniac</option>
            <option name="LR" value="6">Vet 2Handed Sword</option>
            <option name="LR" value="9">Armed Citezen</option>
            <option name="LR" value="55">Archer</option>
            <option name="LR" value="24">Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="159">Composite Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="125">Cultist Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="45">Cultist Fanatic</option>
            <option name="LR" value="125">Desert Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="180">Dragon Claws</option>
            <option name="LR" value="470">Dragon Fire</option>
            <option name="LR" value="5">Flame Bearer</option>
            <option name="LR" value="45">Halberdier</option>
            <option name="LR" value="19">Lancer</option>
            <option name="LR" value="125">Longbowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="24">Militia</option>
            <option name="LR" value="139">Scout of KG</option>
            <option name="LR" value="59">Sential of KG</option>
            <option name="LR" value="139">Spear Thrower</option>
            <option name="LR" value="8">Spearman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="132">Vet Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="55">Vet Halberdier</option>
            <option name="LR" value="134">Vet Longbowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="52">Vet Spearman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="129">Bear Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="48">Bear Warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="45">Boarder</option>
            <option name="LR" value="125">Cave Hunter</option>
            <option name="LR" value="45">Cave Smasher</option>
            <option name="LR" value="0">Direwolf</option>
            <option name="LR" value="129">Lion Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="48">Lion Warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="45">Nrsmn with Ax</option>
            <option name="LR" value="125">Nrsmn with Bow</option>
            <option name="LR" value="135">Rngd Cultist Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="55">Rngd Cultist Warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="126">Rngd Desert Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="119">Rngd Nrsmn Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="41">Rngd Nrsmn Warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="48">Rngd Saber Warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="45">Saber Warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="45">Shark Tooth Warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="125">Skeleton Bowman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="45">Skeleton Warrior</option>
            <option name="LR" value="125">Stone Smasher</option>
            <option name="LR" value="72">Vet Swordsman</option>
            <option name="LR" value="0">Wolfhound</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          

          <button type="button" id="buton" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
          <br>
          <p id="result">Return</p>
          <p id="result1">Return1</p>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did not you try this by running it ?

Comment: Not so sure what the question is exactly, but you can attach any kind of custom attributes to DOM elements and retrieve them from JavaScript. Good practice has it to prefix them with `data-`.

Comment: You need to learn how to use classes

Comment: I know how to use classes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your HTML code will be invalid if you do that.

According to the [W3C documentation of `<option>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option), it cannot have `name` or `name1` attribute.

**SOLUTION:**

This is a good usecase for `data-` attributes. Use it like this:

```
<option data-name1="C" data-name2="Y" value="M">M</option>
```

[Using data attributes | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Looks like you have lot of options in your dropdown menu. I would suggest using `HTML5 datalist` in this case since it allows the user to search within the options.

[`<datalist>` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

**EDIT:**

To fetch the data attribute of the selected option, please follow the example below:

```js
document.getElementById("selectElement").selectedIndex = -1; // so that no option is selected when the page is loaded

function getData(){
  var e = document.getElementById("selectElement"); // get the <select> element

  var data_name1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset.name1; // get the selected <option> and its name1 data attribute
  document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = data_name1;

  var data_name2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].dataset.name2; // get the selected <option> and its name2 data attribute
  document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML = data_name2;  

  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; // get the value of the selected <option>
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = value;  
}
```

```html
<select id="selectElement" onchange="getData()">
  <option data-name1="1" data-name2="X" value="A">A</option>
  <option data-name1="2" data-name2="Y" value="B">B</option>
  <option data-name1="3" data-name2="Z" value="C">C</option>
</select>

<p>
  <label>data-name1 = </label>
  <span>"</span><span id="data1"></span><span>"</span>
</p>

<p>
  <label>data-name2 = </label>
  <span>"</span><span id="data2"></span><span>"</span>
</p>

<p>
  <label>value = </label>
  <span>"</span><span id="value"></span><span>"</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, the datalist was added. I was thinking something along those lines, but I felt the need to fiish up the project before tidying up. ONe thing- can I use data-names like this- getelementsbydataname?

Comment: @Zack105 We cant use `getelementsbydataname` in that case. Checkout the edit in the answer above. Hope it helps :)